# Cannot scroll terminal in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, scrolling

I have a Debian Virtual Machine running on VMWare Pro 15.
The problem is my laptop doesn't have a separate Page up and Page down key it resides under the 9 and 3 key of my keypad. When toggling numlock (I can no longer type numbers) I cannot scroll in the terminal. Page up returns nothing, the terminal knows I pressed a key but does nothing with it. And Page down just gives me a tilde (~). I tried to edit /etc/inputrc but with no luck at all.

My Keyboard layout is US International, with dead keys.
Laptop: ASUS GL503VM

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your terminal emulator is should be able to scroll in the terminal by using the following keys:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>, which you report does not work. Be mindful that the <kbd>Page Down</kbd> and <kbd>Page Up</kbd> keys could be function keys and require that you press and hold down <kbd>Fn</kbd> in combination with them. ( E.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> )

You should also be able to scroll line by line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> respectively.

You can change these keys, but you will need to provide what specific terminal emulator that you are using as each one will require a different method.